# Newey-West like HAC estimates with non-temporal correlation structure in residuals

Tags: least-squares, econometrics, robust-standard-error, neweywest

Let's suppose I have data with key variables country, company and year (and a load of model variables).  There are many companies per country and many years of observations per company.

Naturally, there are strong residual correlations for observations in the same country and same company.  (There are also correlations in the same year across different companies/countries but I am prepared to ignored these).

My understanding of the Newey-West implementation (at least in R) is that the data is assumed sorted and a lag parameter is specified for serial correlations.  That is, the autocorrelation is effectively assumed temporal.

My first attempt was to sort the data by country (believed to be the key source of correlation in this model) and then company.  But I would like to specify the assumed correlation structure more explicitly.

I am sure this is a standard problem in econometrics and should have a textbook solution, but I can't find it.  Any hints would be appreciated! :)

Comment: It sounds like you may want to cluster standard errors at the firm level? Clustering makes the estimated covariance matrix robust to arbitrary correlation of the residuals within a cluster. Basically, an independent observation becomes a cluster.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewGunn do you have a link to describe exactly what you mean by "cluster standard errors at the firm level"?  perhaps a link to some lecture notes?

Comment: Google for "cluster standard errors" and a million things will come up.

Comment: Yes thanks but I was hoping for a more specific and useful reference from someone familiar with the topic.

Comment: Try page 231 of this, " Clustering and Serial Correlation in Panels": https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Joshua_Angrist/publication/51992844_Mostly_Harmless_Econometrics_An_Empiricist's_Companion/links/00b4953344a9a0cb13000000.pdf?origin=publication_detail

Comment: Cheers I'll take a look